# How to automate the Android Standard Browser

Tags: android, selenium, appium, android-espresso

I want to test a few websites with the Android Standard Browser. Ideally I want to use `Appium` or `Espresso`, but while I find instructions on how to test automate apps with them, I can't find the same for automating the Android browser (not Chrome, FF or another browser).

I want to be able to call up the browser, navigate to a website, click on elements etc. Things I've done with Selenium before.

Is there a way to do this with `Appium` and/or `Espresso`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already installed android sdk and configured path skip step 1.

Step1:
To  configure your sdk path in .bashrc file

Type 
       gedit .bashrc at terminal

Opens an text editor, type the folowing and save

```
  export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/adt/sdk"

  export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"

  export PATH=${PATH}:~/adt/sdk/tools

  export PATH=${PATH}:~/adt/sdk/platform-tools
```

Step2: 
Then type uiautomatorviewer at your terminal to start uiautomatorviewer and get details of elements you want to inspect.

Sample code for reference:

```
import os

from time import sleep


import unittest

from appium import webdriver


# Returns absolute path relative to this file and not cwd
    PATH = lambda p: os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), p))
class SimpleAndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
#Specify platform below(Android, iOS)
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
#Specify OS version(Settings->About phone -> android version)
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.4.4'
#Obtain the Device name from Adb[For Android](Terminal Command: "adb devices")
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'TA93304QZD'
#Specify the path to Application
        desired_caps['app'] = PATH('Media Drive-com.sandisk.scotti-55-v2.0.3.apk')

        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

    def tearDown(self):
        # end the session
    self.driver.quit()

    def test_images_copy(self):
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

        for i in range(0,4):
            self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Next").click()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Close").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("OK").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Photo").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/btn_Switch_Local").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("com.sandisk.scotti:id/txt_Name").click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SimpleAndroidTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Answer (score 0):

Appium are being a bit ambiguous about this and can't seem to decide if android browser is or isn't supported.

According to the Appium doc, you can use the Android browser:
http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?python#mobile-chrome-on-emulator-or-real-device

From server capabilities section:

> browserName   Name of mobile web browser to automate. Should be an empty
>   string if automating an app instead.  ‘Safari’ for iOS and ‘Chrome’,
>   ‘Chromium’, or ‘Browser’ for Android

But there is no reference to it in the code and I haven't been able to get it to work.